# Where did my bitcoin go?

Tags: wallet, coinbase.com

Wanted to combine bitcoin on coinbase with bitcoin in wallet. Think I did it wrong. Can’t remember exact steps but think I went on „swap“ for some reason. Thought I was transferring from coinbase to wallet. But bitcoin never arrived there. Had many confirmations and is completed, wondering where it went though?? Guessing I sent it so Someone and it’s lost, sad but okay, just want to confirm there is nothing I can do!?

Answer (score 0):

> **wondering where it went though?**

If you have a Bitcoin transaction-ID and multiple independent [blockchain explorers](https://www.google.com/search?q=blockchain+explorer) show that transaction-ID having multiple confirmations and that specific transaction has an output that pays the expected amount to an address you created using your wallet -- then the money is in your wallet even if your wallet software application doesn't know about it for some reason.

Remember that wallets (real Bitcoin wallets, not third-party custodial accounts pretending to be wallets) don't contain money, they contain the secret numbers known as private keys which are used to control amounts of money. So Bitcoin money is never really in transit and it cannot really go astray or get lost in the network.

> **just want to confirm there is nothing I can do!?**

If you sent money from an account provided by the business named Coinbase, you can, and should, ask them for help.

If you sent money to a normal Bitcoin wallet (non custodial like Bitcoin core, Electrum etc), you can ask the appropriate support forums or ask people here for help -- but you might have to provide details of exactly what software wallet you use and maybe the transaction-ID.

Comment: Okay that sounds sort of promising that it hasn’t vanished   the „wallet“ app is connected to coinbase and therefore I was assuming it would show up in there (as it had previously, although I‘m sure I did it differently last time). Sounds like best bet is to contact coinbase and see what’s going on.  
Not sure how to upload a photo but yes it has all the things you mentioned with blockchain explorers. 
Thanks so much for your answer, I really appreciate it! 